# Inline edit form in Angular.Js

Tags: forms, angularjs, edit

I am trying to make a small app with items pulled from a json source and i want a form to edit each element. Each element has several attributes, name, id, description.

Here is the example but the edit form does nothing at the moment. I will later use the example to store the data in a database.

I am trying to find out the best solution to have this edit form directly on each element when pushing on edit for example. What is the best way to do it?

Thanks in advance!

**script.js**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

function Controller($scope) {

var items = [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "John",
        "price": "55.33",
        "description": "Lorem ipsums aute irure doln v anim id est laborum.",
        "flag": "0"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Mike",
        "price": "68",
        "description": "Loriannaj jh said ihsa djni cjipsums aute irure doln v anim id est laborum.",
        "flag": "0"
    },
    {
        "id": "15",
        "name": "George",
        "price": "78",
        "description": "This is the description",
        "flag": "1"
    }
];
    //Initialize the controller and the UI
    $scope.items = angular.fromJson(items);

}
```

**html**

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <title>Test Page</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <!-- Angular Staff -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
<header>
</header>
<section>

<div class="columns2" ng-controller="Controller">

    <div style="width: 500px; display: inline-block">
        <h3>ITEMS</h3>
        <div ng-repeat="item in items">
            <div class="user_div" >
            <a href="#" ng-click="showDetails = ! showDetails">{{item.name}} </a>
            <a style="float: right" href="#" ng-click="showEdit = ! showEdit">Edit </a>
            </div>

            <div class="user_data" ng-show="showDetails" >{{item.description}}</div>
            <div class="user_data" ng-show="showEdit" >
                <h3>Edit Item</h3>
                <input  value="{{item.name}}" type="text"  >
                <input  value="{{item.description}}" type="text" >
                <button  ng-click="editItem({{item.id}},{{itemName}},{{itemDescription}})">Edit</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <br>

        <pre>Items: {{items|json}}</pre>    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is the example?

Comment: `Here is the example` where?

Comment: sorry missed it. Here is the example code

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same requirement and came up with this solution:

```
<tr ng-repeat="transaction in data.transactions">
 ...
 <td>
 <input ng-model="transaction.numAvailable" 
        ng-style="!transaction.edit && {'background-color': '#eeeeee'}"
        ng-blur="saveShelf(transaction)"
        ng-click="editShelf(transaction)"
        class="form-control" 
        ng-value="transaction.numAvailable"/>
 </td>
</tr>
```

And in my controller.js:

```
$scope.editShelf = function(trans){
  trans.edit = true;
};
$scope.saveShelf = function(trans){
  trans.edit = false;
  //call service to save value
};
```

Basically, you have an input that looks disabled with bg-color:#eee, onclick removes the bg-color, onblur resets the bg-color. To make this work I added an 'edit=false' to my list with [lodash](http://lodash.com/):

```
_.forEach($scope.data.transactions, function(trans){
   trans.edit = false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [x-editable](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/) for inline edit. As we can't see any example , you can use this module for inline-edit.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a factory like this

```
app.factory('userFactory', function ($http) {
    var factory = {};
    factory.get = function () {
        return $http.get('your_rest_url', {}).then(function (resp) {
            console.log('Success', resp);
        }, function (err) {
            console.error('ERR', err);
        });
    };
});

inject it to your controller
var Ctrl = function ($scope, userFactory) {
    $scope.items = userFactory.get();
};
```

then bind the data to your form elements

```
<input ng-model="items.property">
```

Comment: My problem is how to implement the inline edit form. Do i need directives for that?

Comment: I see, well then abstract the part where you want to repeat for every form element and then create a directive with that.  Or you can have a inline-edit directive and just plug it in where needed.